# Visual Studio 2015/2017 Missing features when open project that targeting UWP project?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have installed Windows 10 SDK (build 10240, 10586 and 14393) from standalone and I have project that targeting Windows 10 build 10586, but when I open the project it shows "Missing features". Am I missing something or what?

Comment: VS UWP Tools has installed ?

Comment: Actually, I have fixed by downloading VS UWP Tools again. Do you know where is VS UWP Tools to download offline?

Comment: In VS 2017 offline download is possible but VS 2015 it won't support offline installation of UWP tools

Comment: I agree, I have VS 2017 offline by the way.